# Can't open design view on Visual Studio 2019 C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I've seen this problem on google a few times and I've seen people solve it, but whatever solution I saw and tried didn't work. I saw things like

putting the "public partial class Form1 : Form" first, or pressing F7, or using the View tab to-go-to designer and etc, none has worked. I did manage to look at another file code Form1 Designer, but it was a code as well, different than the form's code but still code, and when I run it it shows a blank page meaning that code does work, I just can't visualize it. Can anyone help me, please?

Appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Did you create the form using the designer?  For the designer to work, the [FormName].Designer.cs file has to be in a format that the designer expects.  If it's not, you will usually get a rather verbose (and somewhat intimidating) error when you try to open it.  Can you open the designer on a form in an existing project?

Comment: I did not create any of them, once I created the project it created it all automatically and put it on the code instead of the design view, and I don't know how to go to the design view

Comment: Are you targeting .net core? Or .net framework?

Comment: I don't even know, how can I check?
I do have framework as a dependency so I assume framework?
But inside the framwork it says something about .net core so I don't know
I am new to Visual Studio.. sorry for these questions

Comment: Open Visual Studio.  Choose File-> New Project.  Use the Search box to find "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) C#".  Choose a Name, a location and a Framework version and press OK.  After a few moments, VS should open an empty form named "Form1" in the designer.  If you don't have the "Toolbox" open, open it (View -> Toolbox).  If the form is selected in the designer you should have a toolbox full of controls available.  Double-click on "Button", and a button should show up in the view.  Double-click on the button and you should end up in your button click handler in Form1.cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the target framework of your project, you can follow `Project -> Properties... Application`. And then you can see the target in the page.

[image]

If the target is `.Net Framework`, you can follow the steps provided by `Flydog57`.

If it is a `Windows Forms App(.Net Core)`, there is no `Designer` by default.

The .NET Core Windows Forms designer is available with the Visual Studio 16.5 Preview 1. So you can try to update Visual Studio to Visual Studio 16.5 Preview 1 or a later version.

For more details, you can refer to this blog.

[Updates to .NET Core Windows Forms designer in Visual Studio 16.5 Preview 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-to-net-core-windows-forms-designer-in-visual-studio-16-5-preview-1/)

Comment: Thanks, I can see that, mine is .NET Core 3.1, like in your screenshot.
I'll try to update my visual studio

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot :)